# Updating MathJax with AsciiMath input

Tags: javascript, mathjax, asciimath

I have the following div:

```
<div id="math-display">``</div>
```

The page runs `MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, 'math-display'])` when the page is loaded. `` ` `` is the delimiter for AsciiMath input.

If I were to use latex to enter equations, and wanted to refresh `math-display`, I could run the following code:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Text', MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math-display')[0], 'new latex here'])
```

However, if I were to put AsciiMath input instead of latex, the result is still rendered with latex (even if AsciiMath delimiters are used in the `'new latex here'` string). How do I update the displayed MathJax with AsciiMath input, instead of latex?

If possible, I would prefer not calling `Typeset` to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text()` method only update text of the object instance, and this object already has the type of input as a property. This type of input is defined by the `delimiters` when the object is created.

When you use `text()` you modify the string that was between the `delimiters`, so you don't need `delimiters`, but you can't change input type.

But you can `typeset` a single element. It'll create a new object with the input defined by the delimiters. See snippet for example:

```js
document.querySelector('#switch').onclick = function() {
  //inputJax property defines type of input  
  alert('input type of math-display is: ' + MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math-display')[0].inputJax);
  
  //To change type of input, you can modifiy content of math-display, not of the math object that was generated 
  document.querySelector('#math-display').textContent = "$$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$";
  
  //You typeset only element that has id math-display. 
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, 'math-display']);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML"></script>
<div id="math-display">`sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2`</div>
<button id="switch">Change content</button>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.